# How can I block HTTPS application data by using iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables

I want to block a HTTPS connection after TLS handshake using Iptables. In the other words, I want to allow TCP and TLS handshakes, and then I want to drop the connection. I know that HTTPS is encrypted, but there may be a solution to differentiate TLS handshake packets and application data packets without decrypting them.

Comment: This is unlikely to be feasible in iptables, as it requires you to inspect the contents of the TCP stream. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I just wonder that is there a way to allow TCP and TLS/SSLv3 handshake packets and then block application data packets without SSL inspection. For example, if I can understand data packets using some packet features such as packet size, I can block only data packets without inspecting the contents.

Comment: Not easily. TLS packets are separate from, and don't always line up with, TCP packets, so without stream inspection you can't reliably identify what's going on. Again: What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to do is only accept the SYN, SYN/ACK, ACK packet from the port 443 to allow the handshake and then drop the rest of the packets:

`iptables -A INPUT --protocol tcp --tcp-flags SYN ACK --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT --protocol tcp --tcp-flags FIN RST URG PSH --dport 443 -j DROP`

Comment: Thank you for your response, but my problem is not allowing TCP handshake. I want to allow both TCP and TLS/SSLv3 (in order to construct HTTPS connection) handshakes. After constructing HTTPS connection, I want to block application data.